# How can I present the changes for updated data in Tableau

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I am working on some data-sets which gets updated daily. By updation, I mean that three things happen:
1. New rows get added.
2. Some rows get deleted.
3. Some existing rows get replaced with new values.

Now I have prepared dash-boards on Tableau to analyze daily data, but I would also like to compare how the things are changing daily (i.e are we progressing or making loss from previous day.)

I am aware that we can take extracts from the data set. But if I go this way,  I am not sure how to use all the extracts in one worksheet and compare the info given by all of them.

Comment: I cannot figure out your exact question, please give it a read once again . Is it you want new `KPI`  for your daily data ? or How many rows are getting `inserted`, `deleted`, `updated` in your `database` etc .on daily basis ?

Comment: Ok just to give you an idea I will take an example:
Day 1 -> 100 rows showing a total revenuw of USD 100 million.
Day 2 -> Same 100 rows with updated revenue of USD 110 million.
Day 3 -> 10 new rows added and 5 rows were updated. Total 110 rows with total revenue USD 105 Million.

How will compare all three days using three lines on same worksheet. Remember the data source has content of day 3 now. Hope this helps. Let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: Can you insert an extra column in your datasource like `data_indicator` . This will contain record such as `u` ,`i` or `d` based on data `updated` `inserted` or `deleted` . This might help you in analysis . So your data grain will now increase for further analysis . Hope this helps .

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the privileges of doing that. That is why I thought of taking data extract of db table but that didn't work out for me as multiple extracts can not be used on same worksheet. :(

Comment: The tracking of data change has to be done from Warehouse side,`Tableau` can't track these AFAIK. more info [Slowly changing dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension)

Answer (score -1):

Tableau is simply a mechanism that builds an SQL query in the background and then builds tables and charts and such via that fetched query. This means that if you delete a row from the table it no longer exists so how can Tableau read it?? If anything your DB architecture should be creating new records and giving it a createtimestamp. You would NOT delete a record and put a new one. Then you'll only have one record in that table.... Sounds like a design issue